# How to show reactive forms validation error messages

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular-reactive-forms

Hellow guys,

I'm struggling making a validator for a name input, I just replied the code from the angular wiki and still not working.

Could you please help me to find the problem?

Thanks in advise.

My HTML Code:

```
  <form [formGroup]="formAlta" (ngSubmit)="addRepresentacio()">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="namePro">Nom</label>
              <input id="namePro" class="form-control" formControlName="namePro" placeholder="Nom del professional" required>
              <div *ngIf="namePro.invalid && (namePro.dirty || namePro.touched)" class="alert alert-danger form-danger" role="alert">

        <div *ngIf="namePro.errors.required">
            El Nom del professional es obligatori
        </div>
    </div></form>
```

And my TS Component

```
 formAlta: FormGroup;
 ngOnInit() {
    this.formAlta = new FormGroup({
      idPro: new FormControl(),
      documentTypePro: new FormControl(),
      namePro: new FormControl('',[Validators.required]),
      rProfessional: new FormControl(this.tipusPro),
      firstSurnamePro: new FormControl(),
      secondSurnamePro: new FormControl(),
      businessNamePro: new FormControl(),
      idCli: new FormControl(),
      documentTypeCli: new FormControl(),
      nameCli: new FormControl('',Validators.required),
      rClient: new FormControl(this.tipusCli),
      firstSurnameCli: new FormControl(),
      secondSurnameCli: new FormControl(),
      businessNameCli: new FormControl(),
      idPermis: new FormArray([]),
      dateFiPermis: new FormArray([])
    });
  }
```

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: Could you describe what does not work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should create a getter method in your component.ts as follows to get the form control in template

```
get formAltaControls(): any {
   return this.formAlta['controls'];
}
```

In your componen.html

```
<div *ngIf="formAltaControls.namePro.invalid && (formAltaControls.namePro.dirty || formAltaControls.namePro.touched)" class="alert alert-danger form-danger" role="alert">

    <div *ngIf="formAltaControls.namePro.errors.required">
        El Nom del professional es obligatori
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice I forgot it :)

Comment: @Bear, you can use in the .html directtly `formAlta.get('namePro')` or `formAlta.controls.namePro` to referred to the control. Tip, use the "safe" operator to get error `formAlta.get('namePro').errors?.required`

Answer (score 4):

I think you have to change your code with something like that

```
  <form [formGroup]="formAlta" (ngSubmit)="addRepresentacio()">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="namePro">Nom</label>
          <input id="namePro" class="form-control" formControlName="namePro" placeholder="Nom del professional" required>
          <div *ngIf="formAlta.controls['namePro'].invalid && (formAlta.controls['namePro'].dirty || formAlta.controls['namePro'].touched)" class="alert alert-danger form-danger" role="alert">

    <div *ngIf="formAlta.controls['namePro'].errors.required">
        El Nom del professional es obligatori
    </div>
</div></form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You input field may like bellow if you input empty
[image]

**In html you may use bellow like**

```
<form class="brown-text" [formGroup]="basicInfoForm">
           <input type="text"  class="form-control"  formControlName="firstName" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': (basicInfoForm.controls.firstName.errors) || (!basicInfoForm.controls.firstName.pristine && basicInfoForm.controls.firstName.invalid) }">
               
                <!-- Validation messages -->
              <div class="invalid-feedback"  *ngIf="(basicInfoForm.controls.firstName.errors) || (!basicInfoForm.controls.firstName.pristine && basicInfoForm.controls.firstName.invalid)">
              <div *ngIf="basicInfoForm.controls.firstName.errors">Name is required</div>
              <div *ngIf="basicInfoForm.controls.firstName.errors">Only Alphabets with space  between 2 to  20   characters</div>
            </div>
   <form>
```

In **.ts** file you may use bellow like

```
  this.basicInfoForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName: new FormControl("Enter First Name", [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.PAT_NAME)])  

  });
```